# Compiling 32-bit app on x86_64 gcc increases app size drastically compared to x32 gcc

Tags: c, gcc

I have a small C program that was is intended to be 32-bit app for compatibility. Later I changed my gcc to x86_64 from x32. And now my program compiles in 64-bit app, which I don't won't to be.
I made it compile with -m32 and windres -f 386pe to force 32-bit, but the application size went up from 47 kB to 303 kB. I don't understand why the app became so big even though it's supposed to be the same, or I am doing something wrong with it?

My make file is pretty simple (for old 32 bit gcc):

```
all: gcc-test

gcc-test: gcc-test.o icon.o
    gcc gcc-test.o icon.o -o gcc-test.exe

gcc-test.o: gcc-test.c
            gcc -c gcc-test.c

icon.o: icon.rc
        windres icon.rc -o icon.o
```

Now I converted it to x64_86 gcc:

```
all: gcc-test

gcc-test: gcc-test.o icon.o
    gcc -m32 gcc-test.o icon.o -o gcc-test.exe

gcc-test.o: gcc-test.c
            gcc -m32 -c gcc-test.c

icon.o: icon.rc
        windres -F pe-i386 icon.rc -o icon.o
```

And when I am doing the already converted makefile for x86_64 on 32-bit gcc it still becomes 47 kB as it's supposed to be. I think that I forgot to pass something else, it may just allocate a lot of memory for x64, while it's not x64 and not required?

I am pretty sure that's very bad, and it shouldn't be so, how do I make it previous size?

Comment: You ran the size comparison between the **stripped** versions of both binaries, did you?

Comment: @LSerni I don't understand what stripped versions mean.

Comment: The binary created by gcc usually has some extra data attached. The "strip" command removes that (it could be called gcc-something-strip and you might have both a 32 and a 64 bit version). The "real" program is the stripped version, the rest is useful for debugging purposes and *might* be generated by different defaults between the two gcc versions. Before hunting anything else, I'd check that.

Comment: Yeah, that does work perfectly, if I strip with --strip-all the compiled exe on x86_64 compiler it becomes even smaller compared to stripping in x32 as follows 19 for x64 and 24 for x32. But I apparently couldn't strip the .o files before linking, they both break and produce errors, if I strip icon, the icon disappears and if I strip main c file it tries to find winmain although it's a console application.

Comment: No, no, you cannot strip an intermediate file. Only the main binary can be safely stripped; in the intermediate files, the same "extra data" format is used to store relevant information, and stripping those kinds of files will do damage.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you. So my starter guess was correct, x64 just allocates a lot of stuff to debug or for weird linking, while x32 doesn't. Well that makes sense.

Comment: Why do you care about the size of debug binaries? And stripping debug info is not a good idea anyway, how can you debug in that case? Release version must be optimized with `-O2` or `-O3` and the size will be saner

Comment: @phuclv eh, I am talking about the release binary, that's why I care

Comment: By the way various optimizations didn't do anything.

Comment: @eLeCtrOssSnake the command you used above is for debugging and has no option for releasing

Comment: To let the linker stript the executable, add `-s` to its options.